# Not able to get notification

Tags: angularjs, dropwizard, atmosphere, atmosphere.js

i am trying to make push notification using Atmosphere and dropwizard.
here what i am trying to do:
Let say user 1 want to send notification to user 2, so when user 1 clicks on send notification button notification should display to user 2.

NotificationResource.java

```
package resource;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

import org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache;
import org.atmosphere.client.TrackMessageSizeInterceptor;
import org.atmosphere.config.service.AtmosphereHandlerService;
import org.atmosphere.config.service.Disconnect;
import org.atmosphere.config.service.ManagedService;
import org.atmosphere.config.service.Message;
import org.atmosphere.config.service.PathParam;
import org.atmosphere.config.service.Ready;
import org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResource;
import org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResourceEvent;
import org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResourceFactory;
import org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResponse;
import org.atmosphere.cpr.BroadcasterFactory;
import org.atmosphere.cpr.MetaBroadcaster;
import org.atmosphere.handler.OnMessage;
import org.atmosphere.interceptor.AtmosphereResourceLifecycleInterceptor;
import org.atmosphere.interceptor.BroadcastOnPostAtmosphereInterceptor;
import org.atmosphere.interceptor.HeartbeatInterceptor;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import representation.Data;
import utility.JacksonDecoder;
import utility.JacksonEncoder;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;


@ManagedService(path = "/{user}")
public class NotificationResource {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NotificationResource.class);

    @PathParam("user") 
    private String chatroomName; 


    @Inject 
    private BroadcasterFactory factory; 


    @Inject 
    private AtmosphereResourceFactory resourceFactory; 


    @Inject 
    private MetaBroadcaster metaBroadcaster; 

    @Ready
    public void onReady(final AtmosphereResource r) {
        logger.info("Browser {} connected.", r.uuid());
    }

    @Disconnect
    public void onDisconnect(AtmosphereResourceEvent event) {
        if (event.isCancelled()) {
            logger.info("Browser {} unexpectedly disconnected", event.getResource().uuid());
        } else if (event.isClosedByClient()) {
            logger.info("Browser {} closed the connection", event.getResource().uuid());
        }
    }

   /* @Message(encoders = {JacksonEncoder.class}, decoders = {JacksonDecoder.class})
    public Data onMessage(Data message) throws IOException {
        logger.info("{} just send {}",message.getAuthor(), message.getMessage());
        return message;
    }*/

    @Message(encoders = {JacksonEncoder.class}, decoders = {JacksonDecoder.class}) 
    public void onPrivateMessage(Data message,AtmosphereResource r) throws IOException { 
            System.out.println(r.uuid()+"______________");
            // Retrieve the original AtmosphereResource 
            System.out.println("In private notification+++++++++================");
                    factory.lookup("/chat/*").broadcast(message.getAuthor()+"Someone Pinged you", r); 

            }
    }
```

clientjs

```
mode.controller('notificationController',['$scope','atmosphereService','$cookies',function($scope,atmosphereService,$cookies){

        $scope.model = {
            transport: 'websocket',
            messages: []
        };

        var socket;
        user=angular.fromJson($cookies.get('user_details_object'))['user_name'];
        pingUrl='/chat/'+user
        var request = {
            url:pingUrl ,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            logLevel: 'debug',
            transport: 'websocket',
            trackMessageLength: true,
            reconnectInterval: 5000,
            enableXDR: true,
            timeout: 60000
        };

        request.onOpen = function(response){
            $scope.model.transport = response.transport;
            $scope.model.connected = true;
            $scope.model.content = 'Atmosphere connected using ' + response.transport;
        };

        request.onClientTimeout = function(response){
            $scope.model.content = 'Client closed the connection after a timeout. Reconnecting in ' + request.reconnectInterval;
            $scope.model.connected = false;
            socket.push(atmosphere.util.stringifyJSON({ author: "author", message: 'is inactive and closed the connection. Will reconnect in ' + request.reconnectInterval }));
            setTimeout(function(){
                socket = atmosphereService.subscribe(request);
            }, request.reconnectInterval);
        };

        request.onReopen = function(response){
            $scope.model.connected = true;
            $scope.model.content = 'Atmosphere re-connected using ' + response.transport;
        };

        //For demonstration of how you can customize the fallbackTransport using the onTransportFailure function
        request.onTransportFailure = function(errorMsg, request){
            atmosphere.util.info(errorMsg);
            request.fallbackTransport = 'long-polling';
            $scope.model.header = 'Atmosphere Chat. Default transport is WebSocket, fallback is ' + request.fallbackTransport;
        };

        request.onMessage = function(response){
            var responseText = response.responseBody;
            try{
                var message = atmosphere.util.parseJSON(responseText);

                var date = typeof(message.time) === 'string' ? parseInt(message.time) : message.time;
                $scope.model.messages.push({author: message.author, date: new Date(date), text: message.message});

            }catch(e){
                console.error("Error parsing JSON: ", responseText);
                throw e;
            }
        };

        request.onClose = function(response){
            $scope.model.connected = false;
            $scope.model.content = 'Server closed the connection after a timeout';
            socket.push(atmosphere.util.stringifyJSON({ author: $scope.model.name, message: 'disconnecting' }));
        };

        request.onError = function(response){
            $scope.model.content = "Sorry, but there's some problem with your socket or the server is down";
            $scope.model.logged = false;
        };

        request.onReconnect = function(request, response){
            $scope.model.content = 'Connection lost. Trying to reconnect ' + request.reconnectInterval;
            $scope.model.connected = false;
        };

        socket = atmosphereService.subscribe(request);

        $scope.notifyClient=function(name){
                console.log("=="+name);
                socket.push(atmosphere.util.stringifyJSON({author:name, message: "hello"}));
        }



    }]);
```

in run method:

```
 AtmosphereServlet servlet = new AtmosphereServlet();
        servlet.framework().addInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "dk.cooldev.chatroom.resources.websocket");
        servlet.framework().addInitParameter(ApplicationConfig.WEBSOCKET_CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
        servlet.framework().addInitParameter(ApplicationConfig.WEBSOCKET_SUPPORT, "true");

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servletHolder = environment.servlets().addServlet("Chat", servlet);
        servletHolder.addMapping("/chat/*");
```

i can able to connect websocket,when i click "send notification" button from user 1, it invokes $scope.notifyClient but the problem user 2 is not able to see notification.

kindly help me out!!

Answer (score 1):

`request.onMessage` is an event external to the angular digest cycle. You need to wrap your event logic in `$scope.$evalAsync`:

```
$scope.$evalAsync(function () {
    $scope.model.messages.push({author: message.author, date: new Date(date), text: message.message});
 });
```

See: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2605-scope-evalasync-vs-timeout-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but i want to thank you, $scope.$evalAsync works well , in case if we are facing issue like "$scope.apply() is already in progress", i have used $scope.$evalAsync in one of my logic and it works well., but still i am facing problem integrating atmosphere with dropwizard.